# Gulp script build results in extra closing braces

Tags: gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using Gulp with [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular). I'm using this same generator on a couple other projects and works just fine. I spun up a new project and decided to use ES6 instead of CoffeeScript, which is what I'm using on my other projects.

Unfortunately, when I do a `grunt serve`, this is what I see at the end of `.tmp/serve/app/index.js`:

```
// Many lines of irrelevant code omitted

    module.exports = NavbarCtrl;

/***/ }
/******/ ]);

/***/ }       // <-- these lines aren't
/******/ ])   // <-- supposed to be there
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW
```

The last `}` and `])` aren't supposed to be there. I get an error that says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` when they're present. When I remove them, everything works fine.

I don't even know how to troubleshoot this problem. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/issues/457

I had to add the `scripts` task as a dep to `scripts:watch`. After that it worked fine.